# Ruby Regex for string "and/or" as exact match

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out the Ruby Regex for the exact string "and/or". For example, let's say I have a name variable that is "Elvin and/or Jafarli"

```
name = "Elvin and/or Jafarli"
```

and I want to split the name based on the string "and/or". How is that done in Ruby?
This is the final result I am looking for:

```
name.split(some_regex) results in ["Elvin", "Jafarli"]
```

** UPDATE **
This is the current regex that exists in the system

```
names.split(/ (?i)(?:and|or) /)
```

What I want to do is to update the regex to also split on exactly string match like "Elvin and/or Jafarli".

Comment: @Ry-, please elaborate your reasons for closing the question. It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Moderators in this community are pretty harsh I guess..

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It’s not clear where the issue was. If it were, it would probably be a duplicate of a different question (e.g. about including the `/` character in a regex literal). So it’s not likely to help anyone else with a similar question in the future, which is the point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The string `and/or` itself does not contain any regex metacharacter, so a suitable regex would be just `%r(and/or)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another alternative with `|`, and escape the delimiter:

```
names.split(/ (?i)(?:and|or|and\/or) /)
```

or use the alternative regex literal form:

```
names.split(%r{ (?i)(?:and|or|and/or) })
```

Comment: A regular expression _is_ useful for handling potentially variable whitespace around `'and/or'`.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there must be a catch. This seems too easy.

```
irb(main):001:0> name = "Elvin and/or Jafarli"
=> "Elvin and/or Jafarli"
irb(main):002:0> name.split /\s+and\/or\s+/
=> ["Elvin", "Jafarli"]
```

Remember to escape the `/` in the regular expression and account for the surrounding whitespace. `\s+` specifies one or more whitespace characters.